# Separate MIDL project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, midl

I'm trying to make separate project for generated files from `midl` compiler.
I have `.idl` file with `rpc` definitions. `Midl` compiler generates two files. For server and for client. And I need to add symbols from generated files to other projects. 
My question is how to setup properly project for midl compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The midl compiler generates 3 files: header (.h), client stub (.c) and server stub (.c). You should include the header and the client stub in client programs, and the header and server stub in server programs. Read:

1. [Developing the Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373636%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [Developing the Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)